# Scala: Is it possible to constrain a type parameter to be non abstract?

Tags: scala, generics, type-bounds

Scala: Is it possible to constrain a type parameter to be non abstract?

Are any other constraints possible except view bounds, upper bounds and lower bounds for type parameters and abstract type members? In C# for example, which I'm familiar with, you have the additional generic constraints:

where T: Class //Not sure if this covered in Scala by T<: AnyRef

where T: interface

where T: struct

where U: T //naked type constraint

where T: new () //This ensures that a type parameter is non-abstract and allows one to instantiate an object of the type in the generic class.

The last one is particularly important as it allows you to construct your unknown type, although its a shame you can only proscribe a  parameterless constructor.

Can =:= <:< and <%< only be used on method parameters?

In response to the comments, the immediate trigger for the question was the need for a "T: new()" restraint or some equivalent mechanism.

```
class ExampleClass[T <: AnyRef] {
  val example: T = new T()//Won't compile as the compiler  
} //doesn't know if such a constructor exists
```

The uses of some of the C# constraints are particular to the needs of C#. For example one restraint that you don't have in C# that people are always wanting is "T: numericType" That issue is already solved in Scala. I'm still very much boot strapping my way up the Scala language, so aside from the above, I was just trying to clarify exactly what tools are and are not available to me in this facet of Scala syntax, even though I don't know yet exactly how I might want to use them in the Scala context.

I'm not sure if this is fully related but sometimes it seems the compiler (Eclipse 2.1.0.M1 with Eclipse 3.7.2) won't let me instantiate collections of unknown element type. The following code now seems to compiles fine. So I'd like to know what the rules are:

```
abstract class Descrip [T <: DTypes]()
{      
  val hexs: MutableList[T#HexT] = new  MutableList[T#HexT] //compiles fine
  val sides: MutableList[T#SideT] = new MutableList[T#SideT] //compiles fine
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question even means. Can you please include some examples?

Comment: Thanks for this interesting question. Could you also give some practical examples where these constrains are useful?

Comment: @DaveBall Edited again in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need of `new T()` is normally resolved by using `Manifest`s. For example this code compiles:

```
class ExampleClass[T: Manifest] {
  val example: T = manifest[T].erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

The drawback is that if the `T` for which `ExampleClass` is instantiated doesn't have a no-arg constructor it will fail at runtime...

Regarding `Numeric`, `Ordering`, etc., they are *type classes* and are part of the standard library, not part of the language. You can build your own type classes. The case of `Manifest` is special because it do have support from the language to provide the implicit object.

Comment: I haven't looked into Manifests. I didn't know they could be used for that purpose but there doesn't seem much point in learning about them as they're depreciated in 2.10. I have no idea it type tags can replace them for this purpose.

Comment: I still have to study the new additions for Scala 2.10, in particular the reflection API. Don't know how mature it is at this time, but I'd say that given that is a very new feature, going with Manifest is not a "too bad" decision for now... Maybe you should ask for the right Manifest replacement for Scala 2.10 in the scala-user mailing list.